# Virtual hosts in Apache acting according to the HTTP Host?

Tags: apache, virtualhost

I currently have this set up:

xx.domain.com (CNAME)-> user.dyndns.org -> MY IP

Currently I have virtual hosts setup in Apache so that xx.domain.com points to one directory, and xx.domain.com:8080 points to another.

However what I'm trying to accomplish is rather than differentiating by ports, I want to be able to have xx.domain.com and zz.domain.com point to different directories.

How is this accomplished? ServerAlias and ServerName don't seem to work because I suspect that user.dyndns.org is actually the ServerName. Though my guess may be incorrect.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ServerName should work for you.  The HTTP Requests should be coming into your server pointing to the host by the CNAME, not user.dyndns.org -- so you should be OK.  Perhaps yours was a port issue when you tested it did you set zz.domain.com to listen on 80 as well?

http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/vhosts/examples.html

Comment: Dynamic DNS may have some restrictions in this regard though, I'm not sure.

Comment: Can you give me an example? ServerName definitely doesn't seem to have any impact.

Comment: That first example in the above link appears to be similar to what you're going for, with 2 sites listening on the same server/port, for different names.

Comment: Accepted as only answer given.